# Error in search using clause include: entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm using .NET core to develop an entity framework api.
I'm getting this error:

[image]

The error occurs in this excerpt.

```cs
public async Task<Country> Find(long key)
{
    return await _context.Country.Include(m => m.Zone)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == key);
}
```

If I remove the include clause the error disappears.

```cs
public class Country
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Initials { get; set; }
   public int ZoneId { get; set; }
   [NotMapped]
   public virtual Zone Zone { get; set; }
}

public class Zone
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE country (
        id       INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                             UNIQUE
                             NOT NULL,
        name     STRING (20) NOT NULL,
        initials STRING (4)  NOT NULL,
        zoneId   INTEGER     NOT NULL
                             CONSTRAINT [country.zone] REFERENCES zone (id) 
    );

    CREATE TABLE zone (
        id   INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                         UNIQUE
                         NOT NULL,
        name STRING (20) NOT NULL
    );
```

Ps: the intensity in using the include is to be able to load the entire zone entity (id, name, ...) of a given country

Comment: `NotMapped` ? What on earth are you trying to do.

Comment: As @MichaelRandall hints at, you can't use the Include extension on a property with the `[NotMapped]` attribute. Your table definition would seem to imply that it _should_ be a foreign key reference, so it's not obvious what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Michael Randall If I remove "NotMapped", entityFramework tries to find this "zone" column in the base (there is only "zoneid"). This is what I understood ... without the appointment I was getting another error.

Comment: If I remove the checkmark "NotMapped" I am getting the error: "SQLite Error 1: 'no such column: c.ZoneId1'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you must remove `[NotMapped]` from `Country.Zone` property.

`Country.ZoneId` type must correspond to `Zone.Id`, which is `long`.

Finally, you should annotate `Country.ZoneId` as a foreign key:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(Zone))]
public int ZoneId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use NotMapped. Try to put

```
[ForeignKey("ZoneId")]
```

On top of your Zone